# How to get average cpu and memory usage for python process

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a scenario where one process will be running (in this case python process) and I want to collect average CPU usage and memory stats from start of the process till end.

Scenario

```
Process start

Collect average CPU and memory 

Process end
```

I have some idea on using psutil library to get this data.

Can anyone please let me know how this can be achieved with python function?